# MongoDB Document_count data per month

Tags: django, mongodb, date

One of my functions im using to pull count values of MongoDB data is, for me at least, slowing the applicaion down.

Here is the code im using

```
def build_year_graphs(year):

Jan = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-01-01",'$lt':year+"-02-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Feb = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-02-01",'$lt':year+"-03-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Mar = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-03-01",'$lt':year+"-04-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Apr = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-04-01",'$lt':year+"-05-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
May = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-05-01",'$lt':year+"-06-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Jun = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-06-01",'$lt':year+"-07-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Jul = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-07-01",'$lt':year+"-08-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Aug = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-08-01",'$lt':year+"-09-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Sep = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-09-01",'$lt':year+"-10-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Oct = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-10-01",'$lt':year+"-11-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Nov = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-11-01",'$lt':year+"-12-01"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})
Dec = collection.count_documents({'DateTime':{'$gt':year+"-12-01",'$lt':year+"-12-31"}, 'IsAsset':'True'})

YearData ={'Jan':Jan, 'Feb':Feb, 'Mar':Mar, 'Apr':Apr, 'May':May, 'Jun':Jun, 'Jul':Jul, 'Aug':Aug, 'Sep':Sep, 'Oct':Oct, 'Nov':Nov, 'Dec':Dec}

return YearData
```

This returns each month and a value. It works. But its slow.

I feel there is a better way to achieve this.. however i dont seem to be able to acomplish this.

Ive been looking at using mongo .aggregate to do this but in all honesty, its not working for me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided `DateTime` is a `Date` rather than a string (as it always should be) you can do it like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { IsAsset: 'True' } },
   { $set: { DateTime: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$DateTime", format: "%Y-%m-%d" } } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { year: { $year: "$DateTime" }, month: { $month: "$DateTime" } },
         count: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: ["$$ROOT", "$_id"] }} }
])
```

Instead of `$replaceRoot` (which is more generic) you can also use

```
{ $project: {count: 1, year: "$_id.year", month: "$_id.month" } }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the Dates are input like this "2021-03-11", this was not my decision.

Comment: That's a design flaw! Anyway, see my update.

Comment: Really appreciate your Answer @Wernfired. 

The output im getting looks like this

'[{"_id": {"year": 2019, "month": 1}, "count": 25}, ' ......

However, im struggling to get it out like this

'["Year": 2019 {"month": 1, "count": 25}, ' ......

Any suggestions? 

I did try using $project to extend the aggrigate output but it just didnt work either

Kind regards